# Drupal 7 annoying content output

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have tried overriding all of the following templates:

- page.tpl.php
- region.tpl.php
- block.tpl.php
- node.tpl.php

I still at the top of my content region have the following markup:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-content field-type-text-long field-label-above"><div class="field-label">content:&nbsp;</div><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">
```

Each of the above templates have nothing but the very minimum to spit out $content usually.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're looking for [`field.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7).  It's one of those template files, like `html.tpl.php`, that common themes sometimes don't provide default implementations for, so it falls back on the "hidden" implementation that lives in `modules/field/theme`.

Comment: I have never even heard of that template before but have done very little tweaking of Forms. Not sure why this template would be used in the content output of a page though? In any case I will try and see...thanks :)

Comment: It's intended so you can format the output of a particular type of field the way you want.  For example, if you have a "Phone Number" field (machine name `field_phone_number`) in multiple content types, you could create a `field--field-phone-number.tpl.php` to make sure it's formatted the way you want everywhere, without having to make changes to the `node.tpl.php` for each content type it appears in.  Honestly, for my purposes they're usually more trouble than they're worth.